# Package MariaDB-shared requires MariaDB-common, but none of the providers can be installed

Tags: mariadb, dnf

I am trying to update the packages on my CentOS 8 server, but when I run `sudo dnf update`, the following message shows up:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:43:34 ago on Wed 12 May 2021 11:59:25 AM CEST.
Error: 
 Problem 1: package MariaDB-shared-10.3.29-1.el8.x86_64 requires MariaDB-common, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mariadb-connector-c-3.0.7-1.el8.x86_64
  - package MariaDB-common-10.3.27-1.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package MariaDB-common-10.3.28-1.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package MariaDB-common-10.3.29-1.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 2: package MariaDB-shared-10.3.29-1.el8.x86_64 requires MariaDB-common, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mariadb-connector-c-config-3.0.7-1.el8.noarch
  - package MariaDB-common-10.3.27-1.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package MariaDB-common-10.3.28-1.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package MariaDB-common-10.3.29-1.el8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

There is a conflict with packages installed and packages that are available for update. How can I fix this problem so that everything updates smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem. To resolve this you need to set `module_hotfixes = true` in the repository definition in /etc/yum.repos.d. See this MariaDB bug report on the issue: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25675.

Cheers,
David